# Display HTML-formated message box in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The `Browser.msgBox("hello")` method lets me display the text "hello" to the user in a message box, but if I put any HTML in there, for example "Hi **there**", the user just sees the HTML tags.

Is there a way to display a popup with simple HTML to the user from withing google apps script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display a more complex UI, check out the new UIApp service google added:

http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/service_ui.html

The documentation is pretty sparse, so check out their examples:

http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/guide_user_interfaces.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly use UI.showModalDialog.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String)